# Blazor WASM Authorization Policy issue when opening new browser tab

Tags: blazor, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am building a Blazor WASM app and I am struggling with the following:

I have a few Authorization policies dictated by the use of

```
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy"]
```

Everything works great. The policies work fine - users who are authorized to access a certain page can get in whereas users who are not authorized to access a page get a message indicating such.

The issue becomes when I open a new browser window. My assumption (and I could very easily be wrong) is that if I am authenticated in one browser window and I open another browser window, my authentication & authorization persist.

What I have found is that the user is identified as authenticated but they cannot authorize.

Is there something I am missing in my assumption above?

To test the above I added Console.Writeln() commands to identify the claims (which is what enables the policies) but the claims in AuthenticationStateProvider are empty. The user appears **Authenticated** but not **Authorized**.

It's almost like my "session"/"cookies"(?) are tied to that one browser window. If that's the case then is there a way to set the session/cookies/token (whatever is the appropriate nomenclature) to be shared among browser windows?

If that's not possible what are my alternatives?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use Azure AD B2C for authentication and custom claims in my token. The above work fine when I don't open a new browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to this.

Azure AD B2C does not preserve custom claims. I’m not sure exactly why but when a new browser window is opened, the token does not contain the custom claims I include. The only way to get those custom claims is to log out and log back in. That is because I use an API connector to add the claims during sign in.

I was assuming that once the token had the custom claims, the browser would maintain but that indeed makes no sense so therefore the way to re-enrich the token claims is to - for example - call an API if there is a token and add the claims.